# Can we get a global SE search function?

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

As a user I want to be able to, for instance, search for “Homer” or “Herodotus” and see results from across the network, i.e., from History, Philosophy, etc.

It sort of feels maybe like there should be an “affixed” search bar at the top of SE-wide feed (that maybe flows out if you pull down.) Not really sure about optimal UX but I would love this functionality.

(Maybe this already exists and I can’t find it?)

Comment: It exists outside the app, in https://stackexchange.com portal. The search there is global across all sites.

Comment: ["homer"](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=Homer); ["Herodotus"](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=herodotus)

Comment: You have it. http://google.com  Even if they implement global search, it still will be bad.

Comment: In addition to the above suggestions, take note that there's no active development on mobile apps since last year, and unknown decision whether to continue it in the future.